# Powershell: Get data from line chart to excel

Tags: powershell

I know we can generate chart from excel/csv data using ms chart library. But my question is little bit different. I am just asking for possibilities.
Is there any way to get the data from excel chart?

For those who wants to know what i did. I search it on google but no related result found. I don't know where to start. So, no code written at the moment. I know how to read excel file in powershell.

Any suggestion.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is data or rather data elements.
What is a chart?  If we think about a chart: It has an X and Y axis:

- It has for the sake of argument and X-axis and we can call that date or data points.
- It has a Y-axis for say quantity.  Your manager may ask, show me how many logins are done per day for the last 30 days?

You would map out by day or by week how many logins were  done and to show this in a "pretty" way: you can do this with a chart.

So, back to your question:

- You need to know - What scale are you dealing with?  Days, weeks, months, number of readings, etc.
- You need to know - What quantity was taken at that time: Days. weeks, months, number of readings, etc.

Once you have both of these, you can then build a chart.  Otherwise, using your Google example: It is just a picture and would be meaningless if there is not thing to tie it for a data relationship.

Hope this helps?